# kdb/q: how to reshape a list into nRows, where nRows is a variable

Tags: kdb

If I am to split a list into 2 rows, I can use:

```
q)2 0N#til 10
```

However, the following syntax does not work:

```
q)n:2
q)n 0N#til 10
```

how I can achieve such reshaping?

Answer (score 2):

Need brackets and semi colon

```
q)2 0N#til 10
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
q)n:2
q)(n;0N)#til 10
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general syntax to split a list in matrix form:

```
               (list1)#(list2)
```

As you can see, left part and right part of '#' is **list**. So here is one example:

```
       q)list1: (4;3)    / or simply (4 3)
       q)list2: til 12
       q)list1#list2
```

We can make an integer list in 2 way:

1. Using semicolon as list1:(2;3;4)
2. Using spaces as list1:(2 3 4)

But when you have variable, option 2 doesn't work;

```
       q)list1: (n 3)    / where n:2
       q) `type error
```

So for your question, solution is to use semicolon to create list:

```
       q) list1:(n;0N)
       q) list1#til 10
```